# Error on Yowsup Echoclient : "InvalidMessage or KeyId for 91XXXXXXXXXX, going to send a retry"

Tags: python, git, whatsapp, yowsup

I have set up an Echoclient of Yowsup. However, randomly I receive an error "InvalidMessage or KeyId for 91XXXXXXXXXX, going to send a retry" while reading incoming message. After a certain period of time it shows "Storing prekeys". Once this is done the Echoclient works again.

I have already tried the following solutions:

1. Installing python-axolotl from
   https://github.com/tgalal/python-axolotl/tree/develop
2. Changing
   PROP_IDENTITY_AUTOTRUST at axolotl/props.py to TRUE
3. Installing
   develop branch of the the Yowsup repository

But nothing seems to resolve this issue. If anyone has faced and resolved this issue, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed maked this

in yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer_receive.py

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error message when i killed the process before it finish sending the message . This because whatsapp end to end ecryption (i think).

This is what i do

1. Reinstall th whatsapp on android device and send a few message
2. Uninstall the app on device
3. Download newer version of Whatsapp.apk
4. Set the new dexMD5 of new Whatsapp.apk on yowsup on env_android.py (and change Whatsapp version too on that file)
5. Build and install using yowsup-cli
6. Request registration code using yowsup-cli
7. Register with new code using yowsup-cli
8. Use new password at config file

And everything back to normal